# Symbol for Universal Set in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, latex, equations, equation-editor

I want to find a way to insert this symbol circled in orange.(Universal set notation used in a particular maths syllabus.)

[image]

Attempts so far.

1. Different scripts of "E" in Microsoft Word. (Palace Script, Edwardian Script, etc)
2. Using \mathcal{E} in LaTeX which yields this.

However, none of them are the same and I am curious to know what kind of typesetting they used. (Word, Tex or some other stuff)

Comment: You might want to play with [shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/), which tries to lookup a Unicode character based on your drawing of it. But I tried it four times, and the best result I got was the Arabic sign misra ( ؏ , U+060F), which is clearly not what you want. (Maybe your freehand drawing skills are better than mine.) Note also that this is a non-standard symbol; [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_set) says that the most common symbols for the universal set are V, U and ξ (lower-case Xi, U+03BE).  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  [This](http://www.singaporeolevelmaths.com/e-math-set-notations/) is the only place I could find your “E” symbol for the Universal set (displayed as an image, unfortunately).  [Wikihow](https://www.wikihow.com/Sample/Calligraphy-Alphabet) shows a Calligraphy “E” that is close to what you want, but they don’t seem to offer any way of displaying it electronically, either.

Comment: In Word, click Insert, in the Symbol group, click Symbol > More Symbols, check if the picture is what you want: https://ibb.co/ce6xwy

Comment: @Scott. I am afraid I got the Arabic sign misra as well when I tried the shapecatcher. I agree that this is not a very common or standard notation which is another reason why I can't seem to find the correct symbol used.

Comment: @WinniL, I did scan through the symbols but I couldn't find anything similar enough.

Comment: @WinniL: As your image shows, the symbol you located is ξ (small (i.e., lower-case) Xi, U+03BE), which I mentioned in my comment, and which is not quite what daruma is looking for.

Comment: With some help from somebody with some typographic experience, it appears as though the font in use is called Adobe Mathematical Pi. It's not a free font but if you use LaTeX, there is a package called mathalfa and inside it there is a script style called MathPi which imitates the Adobe Mathematical Pi very well.

Comment: The symbol is ℰ which is U+2130. As for exactly what font the IGCSE use I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Try typing 'E' in Kunstler Script in MS Word. IGCSE Math papers in a particular syllabus uses that.